# Getting the reference to parent controller of the UIBarButtonItem when pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a instance of UINavigationController namely N declared for my UIPopoverController in a method. I have two UIViewController namely A and B. Initially when I load the popover I assign viewcontroller A to my navigation controller N so A's view get displayed. At this point when N displays A, N has done button of type UIBarbuttonItem assigned as rightNavigation item and calls a method namely M().

So Here is the Question- When I press Done I need to load view controller B in the called Method M(). That is push B in N but for doing that I need the instance of navigation controller N from the UIBarButtonItem that I pressed. I assumed some thing like

```
-(void)M:(id)sender
 {
      UINavigationController *N = barButton.parentController;
     [N pushViewController:B animated:NO];
 }
```

But I didnt arrive to any solution. Can someone please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In method B, you use :

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ac animated:YES];

//ac == UIVIewController which you want to push

Comment: I didnt get you at all. How can I use self.navigationController here? My navigationController (namely N) is a instance within a method and B is a viewController, not a method.

Comment: You have a navigation contains UIViewController, is it right? If YES, in (void)M:(id)sender you can call self.navigationController to push another UIViewController. It must work.